# Visualize 3D data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have data on the form `(x, y, z, v)`, in other words three spatial coordinates and one velocity magnitude. I would like to plot this in 3D, where the velocity magnitude is shown using color.

What is the best way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have trajectory data, so that your spatial coordinates represent the trajectory through space of one or more particles. In that case:

Have a look at [`quiver3`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) or [`coneplot`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/coneplot.html).

If you want colored arrows, then have a look at [`quiver3d`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6066-quiver3d) or [`quiverc`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc) (2D only) on the File Exchange.

If you only have 3 spatial coordinates and *speed* (= velocity magnitude), then your best bet is [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html).

I could go on, but could you give me a bit more detail on what you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I have three spatial coordinates, `x, y, z` and three velocity components `vx, vy, vz`. It describes the flow around a car, so my data is taken from the surface of the car -- and I basically want the direction and magnitude of the velocity shown. `coneplot` actually looks promising for this, what do you say?

Comment: @BillyJean: Yes, that one is made for this :)

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing me in that direction. In the example they use matrices, and not vectors though? Do you have a MWE? Thanks so far, really pushed me forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `surf(x,y,z,v)`?

Comment: This is only useful if the data forms a surface rather than a volume. If there are multiple z values for each x-y pair, then you can't use this approach.